Is the relation obtained through separation of variables solution of an ODE always a function?
I am trying to understand whether the relation $R(x,y)=0$ obtained when solving ODES through seperation of variables is always satisfied by some (differentiable) function (i.e. if there exists a function $\phi:I\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $R(x,\phi(x))=0\forall x\in I$ ) and thus can be considered as a "solution" to the ODE.
For context, this is (roughtly) how my textbook defines an implicit solution to a differential equation:

The relation $R(x,y)=0$ is said to be an "implicit solution" to a differential equation on an interval $I$ iff

There exists a (function $\phi:I\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $R$ i.e.  $$R\Big(x,\phi(x)\Big)=0\qquad \forall x\in I$$
$\phi$ is a solution to the the differential equation


The seperation of variables techniques gives: $$f(y)y'=g(x)\implies F(y)=G(x)+C\qquad (\star)$$
Is the relation given by $(\star)$ always a solution in this sense ( and for every real value of the parameter $C$?), and if so, on what interval exactly?
